# (Kannel) No foreign message ID when sending concatenated messages

Tags: sms, long-integer, message, kannel

I am trying to send multipart (concatenated) messages using Kannel.

Currently, Kannel is configured to call a dlr url (which is a PHP script) that does some stuff with the delivery report.

When sending single message (ie a message that has 10 characters), it does get delivered to my mobile phone and Kannel calls the dlr url twice, both times returning the foreign message ID - both when the dlr status code was 8, which means that it was accepted by SMSC, and when the dlr status code was 1, which means the message was delivered (as it really was).

Now, that works all great but when I try to send a multipart message (ie a message that has 250 characters), it again gets delivered to my phone as one message (as I set the `concatenation` parameter to `true`), but when Kannel called that dlr url when status code was 8 (accepted by SMSC) - it didn't provide any foreign message id, as it would normally in the previous example with message of 10 characters.

I could see in the logs that Kannel indeed received two foreign message ID's from the SMSC (ie 123 and 124), but when calling the dlr url on status code 8 (accepted by SMSC) Kannel never provided those IDs so the field in the database I use to store these IDs has been set from NULL to an empty string.

What is really confusing is that once the multi-part message got delivered to my phone, Kannel called that dlr url again with status code of 1 (delivered) and it passed the foreign message id of the first message, which is what I want to be passed on any status code.

**So my question is** - how can I make Kannel use that foreign message id when calling the dlr url when status code is 8 (accepted by SMSC)? It works when status code is 1 (delivered) but not when status code is 8.

Note: I am using Kannel 1.4.4 but I am willing to upgrade if there's a newer version with this feature included.